# Error when I add webview_flutter : Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, webview

I am getting the following Error When I run the flutter project only after installed webview_flutter plugin.

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

I am already using firebase in the app. some searches saying this is the problem related to the firebase. Searches are giving following solutions. I have tried all of them. but still getting the same.

Migrating to Android X, Making  `multiDexEnabled true` in android build.gradle,

Comment: You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews. Maybe it could help!

Comment: did you solve this?